# How do I make a ListView scrollable inside a NestedScrollView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to create an activity for the history of something.
So I created a NestedScrollView (new > activity > scrollingActivity) with a ListView.
If the items of the list on the bottom go out of the screen, it's not possible to scroll down more.

**How can I make the ListView scrollable inside the NestedScrollView?**

content_history.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="net.thomi100.allintom.HistoryActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_history"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Java class HistoryActivity:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String[] list = {};
    ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        List.add(i + "-Test");
    }
    ListView listView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(listView.getContext(), R.layout.history_list_item, List.toArray(list));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**activity_history.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.thomi100.allintom.HistoryActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_history" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Unclear why you need to nest the listview at all

Comment: Because it looks nice. Not good?

Comment: I'm simply asking what else is in your view that requires the NestedScrollView? The collapsing Toolbar? If you remove that feature and the NestedScrollView, does the ListView alone scroll correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's the CollapsingToolbar. I replaced the NestedScrollView with a RelativeLayout and it scrolls correctly, just the Toolbar does not move.